# Opera browser extension extension-reload via function

Tags: opera, reload, browser-extension, opera-extension

I'm developing an extension for Opera Browser and I'm searching for a function that is able to reload an Opera extension or an alternative way to solve my problem. I want the user to be able to switch between an old version of the extension (the list view or 'newmenu') and the new version (the normal view or 'oldmenu').

The code to do this is as follows:

```
<a id="switch" href="javascript: void(0)" onClick="widget.preferences.version = 'newmenu'; document.getElementById('switch').innerHTML = 'Please reload the extension';">[Switch to Normal View]</a>
```

The **widget.preferences.version = 'newmenu'** in this **oldmenu.html** file, sets the user preference to use the new menu and **widget.preferences.version = 'oldmenu'** (not shown here), which is located in the **menu.html**, sets the user preference to use the old menu.

Then, in the **index.html** file, the extension checks whether it has to show the old menu or the new menu.

```
if (widget.preferences.version == "oldmenu") {
   var ToolbarUIItemProperties = {title: "4chan Boards", icon: "icons/icon_64x64.png", popup: {href: "oldmenu.html", width: 220, height: 620}}
} else {
   var ToolbarUIItemProperties = {title: "4chan Boards", icon: "icons/icon_64x64.png", popup: {href: "menu.html", width: 250, height: 350}}
}
```

Now, the problem is that for this code to execute, the user has to manually reload the extension, which is very ugly.

And well, since the Opera Developing Forum is currently unreachable (bad gateways and long loading times), I guess this is the best place to ask my question. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this line solved part of the problem. The line is located in **index.html**.

```
theButton.onclick = function(){if (widget.preferences.version =="oldmenu") {theButton.popup.href = "oldmenu.html";}; if (widget.preferences.version == "newmenu"){theButton.popup.href = "menu.html";};};
```

Also, just changing these lines a bit and adding a href, made it real quick to switch between menu's. This was not an option before, since it would only switch once and switch back automatically when you re-open the the button.

```
<a href="oldmenu.html" onClick="widget.preferences.version = 'oldmenu';">List view</a>
<a href="menu.html" onClick="widget.preferences.version = 'newmenu';">[Switch to Normal View]</a>
```

However, I didn't manage to change the heigth and the width of the popup in this manner. So, I just made a compromise between the two menu's ;)